# How to get the basic mail command in ubuntu 10 to work

Tags: email

I am a college lecturer to whom the task of supporting the students' Linux Server has fallen. My students just need to use the mail command to communicate with me and each other. I thought mail would be there by default but it wasn't. I have tried all the advice I found on the Internet and tried to install mailutils, sendmail, mailx, exim4 and postfix. There were more but I can't remember them all now.  After installing (if it works - some of them don't), when I try to send a message they all  give me:
/usr/sbin/sendmail: file or directory not found. 
I don't need anything fancy - we don't need to access remote email, just locally on our server.
Incidentally the same problems are occurring on the physical server and my test virtual machine, installed at different times but both Ubuntu 10.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend this tutorial:

http://www.notesbit.com/index.php/scripts-unix/sendmail-introduction-and-configuration-a-step-by-step-guide-for-those-of-you-configuring-your-first-e-mail-server/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

When you install this, the installer should try to walk you through a basic configuration.  If it doesn't, there may be a preexisting configuration file.  You can force a reconfigure by running:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Based off of your needs, you can just choose the "Local only" option from the configuration menu.

If you still get:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail: file or directory not found
```

post back the output of:

```
dpkg -l postfix
```

This will let us know if postfix didn't completely install for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a plain and simple mail program to run from command line, you could install alpine. It should be in apt.

It will give you easy access to the inbox and to posting new e-mails.